# MVC5 view drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-mvc-views

In a C# MVC5 Internet application view, how can I display a dropdown list for a user to select a list item that is populated from a `View Model` list?

Here is the `ViewModel` code:

```
public class MapLocationItemViewModel
{
    [Editable(false)]
    public int mapLocationForeignKeyId { get; set; }
    public List<string> mapLocationItemTypes { get; set; }
    public MapLocationItem mapLocationItem { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code that I currently have in the `View`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.mapLocationItem.mapLocationItemType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.mapLocationItemTypes)
    </div>
</div>
```

Each item in the `mapLocationItemTypes` is currently being displayed as a `class="text-box single-line valid"`.

Is there a MVC View tag that will display a list that is populated from a `list<string>` or an `array`?

I have tried the following code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.mapLocationItemTypes)
```

However, I am getting a compilation error, and am not sure as to the value(s) for the overloaded method.

How is the best way to display a list in a view, so that the user can select an list item from the list?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Model :

```
 public List<SelectListItem> mapLocationItemTypes { get; set; }
 public int mapLocationItemVal { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.mapLocationItemVal , new SelectList(Model.mapLocationItemTypes , "Value", "Text"), "  -----Select List-----  ")
```

here in above example the 3rd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` i.e. `" -----Select List----- "` will be the initial selected item of your dropdown with value equal to  `''`.

At Controller during POST `mapLocationItemVal` will have selected dropdown value.

The above shown code is best and simplest way to bind Dropdownlist in MVC.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. However, how can I use the bootstrap style dropdown list?

Comment: Bootstrap is just a framework used for styling web apps ... you can use bootstrap styled dropdown also in MVC very easily...@user3736648

Comment: you can give bootstrap css style to DropDownfor() as @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.mapLocationItemVal , new SelectList(Model.mapLocationItemTypes , "Value", "Text"), "  -----Select List-----  ",new{ @class = "form-control" })--@user3736648

Comment: @user3736648-I think above comments will help you...if you need more help then comment...

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

I assume you need to fill `mapLocationItem.mapLocationItemType` based on the selected value when you post the data.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.mapLocationItem.mapLocationItemType, new SelectList(Model.mapLocationItemTypes))
```

If you want to add CSS class you can do it as below.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.mapLocationItem.mapLocationItemType, new SelectList(Model.mapLocationItemTypes), new { @class = "your-class" })
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. However, how can I use the bootstrap style dropdown list?

Comment: You can add `html attributes` within `DropDownListFor` helper, I have updated the answer. Anyway you don't need to add additional property to your model as the other answer since you already have the `MapLocationItem` property in your model. If you try this way, `MapLocationItem`'s `mapLocationItemType` property will be filled on submit.

Answer (score 2):

Create a method in your controller

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{
   SampleDBContext db = new SampleDBContext();
   ViewBag.table_name = new SelectList(db.table_name, "DataValueField", "DataTextField");

   return View();
}
```

View of the Controller

```
@Html.DropDownList("table_name", "select a item")
```