# Create a DropDownList in MVC5 for a foreign key value using EF6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

I've been googling for 3 days now and I'm totally lost between different methods of doing what I want. I want to add a DropDownList to my view for a foreign key.

These are my model classes:

```
public class PaymentType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Payment 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Payment()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then I add a view for `Create` from model:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Payment</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I tried to add the dropdownlist Like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PaymentType, new SelectList(Model.PaymentType, "Id", "Name", Model.PaymentTypet), "--select--")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

But I get this error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Charity.Models.PaymentType' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

I don't know if the problem is from the model, controller, view or all of them.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because PaymentType field is not a collection. If I understand it correctly, you want to give the user a drop down list with all the payment options in it, and let the user choose one of them? is that right? if so, you have to fetch all the payments from the database  and put them in another filed of model, then pass the model to the view

Comment: check this out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036799/mvc5-view-drop-down-list